# Should we have topic challenges?

Tags: discussion, site-events, challenges

[The idea of topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work) was originally suggested by Jon Ericson and has been used by many sites since. I also mentioned this in a [recent post](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/any-ideas-to-promote-lifehacks) asking for ways to promote Lifehacks.SE.

**How does it work?**

1. Ask for ideas - a post is made asking the community to suggest ideas for the next weekly topic challenge ([home](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home), [cleaning](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning), [food](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food), etc.). These ideas can be tags that are popular now, or tags you think deserve more attention
2. Choose an idea and initiate the challenge - the highest voted suggestion will become the weekly topic challenge and a meta post will be made explaining the tag and telling users that it is the featured tag for the week
3. Tally the results - users who asked or answered at least one question with the tag will be recognized
4. Repeat until we run out of topics

**Should we have topic challenges?** They can be weekly or biweekly. Use this question to post any of your own ideas about improving this idea.

---

*Note: participation is encouraged, but not required*

---

**We will now have biweekly topic challenges. They will start every other Friday. The first one will be Friday, April 24, 2015. Please suggest topics [here](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/what-should-the-themes-for-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be?cb=1).**

Comment: I'm all for these challenges! What about keeping a "leader board" thread to rank the best/highest quality questions with most engagement?

Comment: Are you volunteering to do the associated work to run the challenges? I think it's an *awesome* idea. I started challenges on 4 sites so far so I won't be able to do this one.

Comment: @J.Musser Yeah, I'll run it :)

Answer (score 4):

Yea, I think this site could benefit with topic challenges.

What do you think of doing questions about [car hacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car). For example, any and all questions related to life hacks involving a car would be on topic for this challenge. Whether it's about hacks to fit/put things in a car, hacks related to cleaning parts of the car, hacks related to managing the drivers/passengers comfort while in the car, etc.

Would that be too broad for this? I think it's narrow enough. Whereas "home" hacks would be really broad since there are many different areas and products and stuff in a home.

> Use this question to post any of your own ideas about improving this idea.

I don't think the idea needs any improving at this point. I'd think the best way forward here, is to try it out and see how it goes. If we run into any issues from doing this, we can adjust accordingly for the next week.