# What should the themes for our fortnightly topic challenges be?

Tags: discussion, site-events, challenges

Lifehacks SE will now be starting to do [fortnightly topic challenges](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/should-we-have-topic-challenges) as many other SE sites have done over the years. We need to do a few things before the topic challenges can be started and one of them is to create a post asking for themes for the topic challenges. This will be that post.

The themes for these topic challenges will be tags on this site (ie: [home](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home), [car](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car), etc.). These can be popular tags or tags that you think should get more attention. So, please suggest any tags you think will be good as an answer to this question. Also, vote for your favorite themes. The top theme at the end of every two weeks will be used.

**Note:** Topics that are chosen will be deleted to avoid clutter in the answer section.

---

> **Current Topic:**
>
> [Fortnightly Topic Challenges #3: Camping](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/fortnightly-topic-challenges-3-camping) (May 23 - June 5) suggested by [itlookslikeimaqueen](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/188/itlookslikeimaqueen)

**Previous Topics:**

- [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #1: Car](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-car) (April 24 - May 8) suggested by [michaelpri](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/20/michaelpri)
- [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #2: Summer](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-summer?cb=1) (May 9 - May 22) suggested by [itlookslikeimaqueen](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/188/itlookslikeimaqueen)

Comment: As a note I think that close to global or popular holidays we should feature that tag. As then we can start building tags for Christmas, Easter, Winter, Spring, etc. Basically any notable event. People searching for these key terms might even land on our site and decide to stick around.

Comment: To stop this page from getting too cluttered I suggest deleting the tags proposals after they are used.

Comment: Ah, this explains the flood of [arbitrarily forced "hack" questions](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/how-to-light-a-match).

Comment: Is this attempt at generating traffic closed down for the summer, or for good?

Comment: @holroy I am hoping to start it back up again soon. I was away for a bit and along with my moderator responsibilities on Health, I began to slack off a bit. Hopefully these will be up and running again soon.

Comment: Let's start doing this again. i can help.

Answer (score 6):

[home](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home) [cleaning](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning)

As most of the people turn their house upside down in summer only. They make drastic changes to their house in this season. As this tag attracts users to lifehacks to post more questions.

Answer (score 6):

[travel](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel)

To me travelling opens up for lots of hacks, so maybe that could be a popular theme?

Answer (score 4):

[headphones](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headphones)

I use my headphones a couple of times a day, but always suffer from tangles, breaks, etc. Lifehacks have saved me from buying more pairs constantly. I would love to see this tag gain more popularity and more posts, as I am sure there are others who also use headphones and can be helped. I would love to learn more hacks to save my headphones.

Answer (score 3):

[pets](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pets)

As one of many pet owners on this site I would love to see this tag gain more relevant posts. This would be valuable for us and others and would add to the relevancy of the site.

Answer (score 2):

[eyeglasses](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eyeglasses)

As a eyeglass wearer I am alway looking for better ways of treating my lens and getting more life out of them. Since a large amount of the world wears or needs glassses, I would love to see this tag gain more post and popularity. I feel that hacks to increase the life of your glasses or to help anyway with them is valuable.

Answer (score 2):

[books](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books)

As a reading enthusiast, I would love to see more posts on this tag. I am always suffering from old book smells, broken books, stains, etc.  Lifehacks can save loads of money and books, with decreased effort, time and spendings. I am always excited about new ways to restore my books, and I am sure there are more people that can benefit from these Lifehacks, as well.

Answer (score 1):

[gardening](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening)

As a avid gardener, I would love to see this tag expanded as I am always looking for new, innovative ways to garden. I think that this is pertinent for any season and would be a interesting topic for many other site users.

Comment: I like this one. I am also an avid gardener, or at least would like to think so...

Answer (score 1):

[technology](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology)

Seems like a nice idea since there are SO many possible lifehacks for so many different things.  They can improve technology, usage (phone stands out of everyday objects) etc.!

Answer (score 0):

[make-up](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/make-up)

The makeup tag is quite small, I would love to get more questions on the topic for the following reasons:

- Makeup is quite well used and expensive(in some cases), if anything can be done to apply it faster, make alternatives, or etc. I think they would be very helpful and well-received.
- Having a good supply of questions of varied topics, like makeup would help direct traffic to our site and help us live up to being a great Lifehack guide.

Answer (score -1):

[efficiency](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency)

This tag is only mildly popular and I would love to get more questions about reducing the time or energy of a task. I think these would be relevant to other users and would be helpful in broadening the site.