# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #1: Car

Tags: discussion, site-events, challenges

Our first fortnightly topic challenge is starting now.

Topic: [car](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car)

Dates: April 24 - May 8

Proposed by:

[image: profile for michaelpri at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]

> Car hacks have been only been mildly popular. I'm sure many people have questions about hacks in the car, so I think this would be a good opportunity to do so.

Go forth and ask questions about car hacks.

On May 8, the stats for the questions and answers received during the challenge will be announced in the answer section below. If you have any questions feel free to ask here or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19330/the-junk-drawer).

---

Propose new topics here: [What should the themes for our fortnightly topic challenges be?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/what-should-the-themes-for-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be?cb=1)

Comment: Can you give same sample in which format the questions should be? Just the plain question, nothing else? Or additional explanation are welcomed.

Comment: @kenorb They should just be normal questions

Comment: @kenorb also, feel free to do a self-answered question to share your knowledge, if you're so inclined, but be sure all the answer is in the answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [car](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car) topic generated only 3 questions and 17 answers, for an average of 3.4 answers per question. Hopefully we do better next time :(

### Questions by date asked (oldest to newest)

1. [How to get home after losing lugnuts?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6702/how-to-get-home-after-losing-lugnuts)
2. [Stop car doors from slamming against wall inside my garage](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/stop-car-doors-from-slamming-against-wall-inside-my-garage)
3. [How to cool a car down quickly](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/how-to-cool-a-car-down-quickly)

### Users who asked

[image: profile for Mooseman at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]

[image: profile for Darren at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]

[image: profile for Darren at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]