# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #2: Summer

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-events, challenges

Our second fortnightly topic challenge is starting now.

Topic: [summer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summer)

Dates: May 9 - May 22

Proposed by:

[image: profile for itlookslikeimaqueen at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]

> I think that since Summer is really close for some of the users here, some more questions with this tag would help boost Lifehacks relevancy. And be helpful for the following months when suffering through Heatwaves, droughts, etcetera.

Go forth and ask questions about summer hacks.

On May 22, the stats for the questions and answers received during the challenge will be announced in the answer section below. If you have any questions feel free to ask here or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19330/the-junk-drawer).

---

**Propose new topics:** [What should the themes for our fortnightly topic challenges be?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/what-should-the-themes-for-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be?cb=1)

---

**Previous Topics:**

- [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #1: Car](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-car)

Answer (score 3):

The [summer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summer) topic generated 11 questions and 34 answers, for an average of 3.1 answers per question. Much better than last time :)

##Questions by date asked (oldest to newest)

1. [Ways to stop your Beach blanket from blowing away](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/ways-to-stop-your-beach-blanket-from-blowing-away)
2. [Comfortable Ways of Riding a Bike Barefoot](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6939/comfortable-ways-of-riding-a-bike-barefoot)
3. [How to Fix a Hole in your Waterproof pool?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6946/how-to-fix-a-hole-in-your-waterproof-pool)
4. [How to remove Sweat stains from clothing?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/how-to-remove-sweat-stains-from-clothing)
5. [4m² Room for Gaming PC - Temperature issue](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6987/4m%C2%B2-room-for-gaming-pc-temperature-issue)
6. [Discourage sand from sticking to body when at the beach](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6990/discourage-sand-from-sticking-to-body-when-at-the-beach)
7. [How to protect my belongings at the beach](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/how-to-protect-my-belongings-at-the-beach)
8. [How can I open the window when it's dark outside without fearing that moths might fly in?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/how-can-i-open-the-window-when-its-dark-outside-without-fearing-that-moths-migh)
9. [Makeshift cooler after buying icecream or beverages at the beach](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/makeshift-cooler-after-buying-icecream-or-beverages-at-the-beach)
10. [Air Conditioner/Coolers best substitute](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/air-conditioner-coolers-best-substitute)
11. [Clothespin alternatives](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7115/clothespin-alternatives)

##Users who asked

[image: profile for itlookslikeimaqueen at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]


[image: profile for Sempie at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]


[image: profile for Darren at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]

[image: profile for Adem at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/flair/6692.png))</sub>

[image: profile for holroy at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]


[image: profile for mustangDC at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]