# Fortnightly Topic Challenges #3: Camping

Tags: discussion, site-events, challenges

Our third fortnightly topic challenge is starting now.

Topic: [camping](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camping)

Dates: May 23 - June 5

Proposed by:

[image: profile for itlookslikeimaqueen at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]

> This tag is not that popular, and I would love it get more popularity as outdoors and camping is very popular and would help boost the diversity of Lifehack questions here. It would really help to have a useful guide on this topic.

Go forth and ask questions about camping hacks.

On June 5, the stats for the questions and answers received during the challenge will be announced in the answer section below. If you have any questions feel free to ask here or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19330/the-junk-drawer).

---

**Propose new topics:** [What should the themes for our fortnightly topic challenges be?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/what-should-the-themes-for-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be?cb=1)

---

**Previous Topics:**

- [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #1: Car](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-car)
- [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #2: Summer](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-summer)

Answer (score 3):

The [camping](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camping) topic generated 4 questions and 8 answers, for an average of 2 answers per question. Not the worst, but we can do better.

### Questions by date asked (oldest to newest)

1. [Ways of waterproofing a watch](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7234/ways-of-waterproofing-a-watch)
2. [How to light a match?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/how-to-light-a-match)
3. [How can I drive a tent peg into gravel?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7242/how-can-i-drive-a-tent-peg-into-gravel)
4. [How to straighten a bent tent-peg](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7243/how-to-straighten-a-bent-tent-peg)

### Users who asked

[image: profile for itlookslikeimaqueen at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]

[image: profile for Oxinabox at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]