# Fortnight Topic Challenge #4: Travel

Tags: discussion, site-events, challenges

Our fourth fortnightly topic challenge is starting now.

Topic: [travel](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel)

Dates: June 6 - June 19

Proposed by:

[image: profile for holroy at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]

> To me travelling opens up for lots of hacks, so maybe that could be a popular theme?

Go forth and ask questions about travel hacks.

On June 19, the stats for the questions and answers received during the challenge will be announced in the answer section below. If you have any questions feel free to ask here or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19330/the-junk-drawer).

---

**Propose new topics:** [What should the themes for our fortnightly topic challenges be?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/what-should-the-themes-for-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be?cb=1)

---

**Previous Topics:**

- [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #1: Car](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-car)
- [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #2: Summer](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-summer)
- [Fortnightly Topic Challenges #3: Camping](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/fortnightly-topic-challenges-3-camping)

Comment: You forgot to edit the last bit while copying this text. I bet it's hard for you to post the stats for the questions and answer before the challenge even started. :P

Comment: @Alex Whoops, didn't even see that. Thanks :)

Comment: Sadly this topic doesn't seem to attract a lot of response. And to further add to that, I just got an YouTube subscription email from [DaveHax](https://www.youtube.com/user/DaveHax) regarding his [favorite travel hacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0rOspAOgx8). Recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The [travel](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) topic generated only 2 (unclosed) questions and 5 answers for 2.5 answers per question. We really need to do a better job with these.

### Questions by date asked (oldest to newest)

1. [Secure hand luggage on airport](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7351/secure-hand-luggage-on-airport)
2. [Cable organisation when travelling](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/cable-organisation-when-travelling)

### User who asked

Only one user this time.

[image: profile for holroy at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]